# Unexpected XML declaration

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I copied some web.config file started to get this error.

> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node
> in the document and no white space characters are allowed to appear
> before it.

But when I check file, everything looks great and there is no problem with the xml formatting.

What may cause to this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so weird and annoying when I got this error. Because as I said previously, when I check the file, everything looks great and there is no problem with the xml formatting.

I thought that might be an encoding issue. And I opened it with notepad and try to save as.

[image]

Then I see the encoding is different than UTF-8. Changed encoding to UTF-8, saved and error is disappeared in Visual Studio.

I really do not if keeping this UTF-8 with BOM is important. I only figured that BOM is Byte Order Mark (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/byte-order-mark)